# Firebase Android get value for unknown key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of objects on my Firebase database, and the key for each object is a timestamp. I can get the last one using `limitToLast(1)`, and the data snapshot I get is:

```
{ key = time_stamps, value = {1510768441759={id=f454445c6e880df31e, coordinates={latitude=-4.1461734, longitude=20.5992437}}} }
```

Where `1510768441759` is the timestamp.

How do I read the coordinates? I've tried to convert the value to a POJO, but I cannot, because the timestamp is unknown to me, and in a POJO it would be the name of a property…

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do it without a parent POJO but only with coordinates pojo you can just do the following by the datasnapshot:

```
Query query = ref.child("time_stamps").orderByKey();
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot item: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
        return;
      }
      for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot :item.getChildren()){
        final String timestamp = childSnapShot.getKey();
        final DataSnapshot parentSnapShot = childSnapShot.child(timestamp);
        if (!parentSnapShot.hasChildren()) {
          continue;
        }
        Double latitude = parentSnapShot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        Double longitude = parentSnapShot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
      }
    }


  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

etc.

Comment: Great answer! You might want to add an example of attaching a listener, especially if you listen for value events and also need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how does this work? Doesn't Op have `id=f454445c6e880df31e` between timestamp id and coordinates? (without POJO one)

Comment: `timestamps` looked like a fixed name to me, so `ref.child("time_stamps").orderByChild("timestamp")...`. Ah, I see now that this is missing from the answer. My fault for scanning too quickly.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's fine :) I was just wondering if I understood it correctly or not :p

Comment: yes sorry guys I showed directly the solution of the problem. but the correct is (I will edit) is `ref.child("time_stamps").orderByKey()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
time_stamp
  1510768441759
      id: f454445c6e880df31e 
              coordinates
                 latitude=-4.1461734
                 longitude=20.5992437
```

try this, assuming you do not have this `1510768441759` :

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("time_stamp");
Query query = reference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(f454445c6e880df31e );
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
           String keys=datas.getKey();
          for(DataSnaphot ds :datas.getChildren()){
           String latitudes=ds.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
           String longitudes=ds.child("longitudes").getValue().toString();
            }
          }


    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The above is done assuming you are on this datasnasphot `time_stamp`. First you do a query to be able to get the coordinates of this `id: f454445c6e880df31e`. Then since you are on this datasnasphot `time_stamp`, you have to loop once to be able to retrieve this `1510768441759`, then loop again to be able to get the latitude and the longitude.